# Get authenticated user data in firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

1. i have a code to display my information after i logged into firebase
       but it only out putted on the console log, thats not what i want i
       want to display the data in my ionic list view.
2. how do i make sure that the authData is still in existence inside my
   scope even though i refresh my browser

here is my controller code:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject){

$scope.formData = { "email": "", "password": "" };

$scope.currentUserName ={}; $scope.currentUserImg ={};

var fb = new Firebase("https://bigzill.firebaseio.com/"); var fbAuth 
= $firebaseAuth(fb); $scope.login    = function(email, password){
    if(email && password){
        console.log("valid Form");
        fbAuth.$authWithPassword({
            email: email,
            password: password
        }).then(function(authData){
            var authData = fb.getAuth();
            var usersRef2  = new Firebase("https://bigzill.firebaseio.com/users/"+authData.uid);

            usersRef2.on("value", function(snapshot) {
              $scope.data = snapshot.val();
              // data equals { "name": { "first": "Fred", "last": "Flintstone" }, "age": 53 }
              //console.log($scope.data.username);  // "Fred"
              //console.log($scope.data.image_name);  // 53

            });
            $state.go('tab.home');
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log("Error: " + error);
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: "Login Error",
                template: error
            });
        });
    }else{
        console.log("Invalid Form");
    } } });
```

HERE IS MY VIEW CODE:

```
<ion-view view-title="Home Page">

    <ion-content class="has-tabs" style="margin-top:25%;">
        <!--search form-->
        <!-- <ion-sub-header>
             <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
                 <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                     <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                     <input type="search" ng-model="query.search.name" placeholder="Search">
                 </label>
             </div>
         </ion-sub-header>-->
        <!--end of search form-->

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="data in data">{{ data.username }}</li>
        </ul>
    </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Please what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

> 1. i have a code to display my information after i logged into firebase but it only out putted on the console log, thats not what i
>      want i want to display the data in my ionic list view.

You just need to set your results of fb.getAuth() to a scope variable then you can iterate over it like any other object. It could be as simple as:

```
$scope.authData = fb.getAuth();
```

And then on the front end:

```
<p>{{authData.username}}</p>
```

It looks like you are trying to ng-repeat.  But getAuth will only return the auth data of the current user, so there is nothing to repeat over. If you want to display all users you will have to create a new child in Firebase to store that data and then you can iterate over that object.

> 2. how do i make sure that the authData is still in existence inside my
>      scope even though i refresh my browser

Your auth data is automatically persisted for 24 hours unless you change the Session Length or explicitly call unauth().  [Relevant doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-persisting-auth)

Comment: thank you sire, but i want to retrieve this username from my firebase node called  user. so please how do i do it.

Answer (score 0):

wow....
the fault was really from me.

---

> what i did was that i was calling my $scope.data in my loginCtrl while
>   my ion-view was calling from HomeCtrl...

---

its working perfectly well now and i thank all of you that put my code to heart to help, i am very grateful for your concern.